# Multipage form not multistep

Tags: forms

Can anyone help me to make multipage form not multistep.
Suppose On front page i have two fields select service and select location and a button and after selecting both clicking on button opens a new form on new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module and create multiple separate forms.

On submission of first (on front page), you can redirect users to another page (another webform) based on their selection using custom redirect in webform settings and tokens `[submission:values:?]` that use data from webform that has been submitted. You just have to set "key" on selects in your form properly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you pls explain about keys ie field key(I guess) and how i will get form 1st data to next page form.

Comment: When you create form element with multiple options (select list for example), each item on that list is defined as pair KEY | VALUE. User can see value while you work with keys when processing results. So you can set one of your "field_service" options to "foo | I need Foo service". User then selects "I need Foo service" and after submission, that form redirects to custom url of specific Foo service form (www.example.com/foo-service-form) by `[submission:values:field_service:key]-service-form`

Comment: How i will use this data in next form

Comment: Adn since those two forms are completely separate, if you need to prepopulate some fields of second from first, you can pass values in URL (by using tokens in redirect url again) and set default values in second form to read those from url query - see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/81182/38635