# UTMs stopped being caught on webform submission

Tags: webforms

Forms has `hidden` inputs in the components to **collect UTM values** from the URL.

[image]

Once the form was filled in, the submission appeares correctly in the results table, both the public fields like the name, surname, etc ... as the content of the utm.

Recently, the new forms created do not store utm values, not even the cloned forms of a functional form.

[image]

Identical forms, in some takes the UTMs (forms with some time), in others not (created / cloned recently). Even shown in the same view.

I have tried to see with the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)  if there was a failure when interpreting the forms or the `hidden` fields ... without result.

Any idea or direction where the problem could go?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using the technique covered in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81182/pass-url-string-to-webform-text-field to fill the fields?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Thanks for your reply, unlike the post you mentioned, the UTM format is: `&utm_unidad=foo&utm_canal=foo&utm_origen=foo`.

Up to now they are automatically filled in, as long as the hidden fields of the form coincide with the fields in the UTM.

Comment: that's curious. I would not expect the fields to be filled in automatically by default. You might want to try explicitly setting a default using eg. "[current_page:query:utm_unidad]".

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong It worked fine! Do you want to write an answer so I can give you rep ? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Answer added @Qu4k3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81182/pass-url-string-to-webform-text-field) provides the method you can use to pass URL query variables into hidden fields in webform.

What you need to do is assign a default value to each field which uses a token representing the query variable. So, for example, the field for "utm_unidad" should have a default value of:

```
[current_page:query:utm_unidad]
```

And so on for the other fields.

Comment: Did this stop working for UTM parameters? If I put in `[current-page:query:your_name]`, it works. But if I put in `[current-page:query:utm_source]`, the result is `value="[current-page:query:utm_source]"`

Comment: @DelfordChaffin is there actually a value for that parameter? If sometimes it may be missing you need to add the suffix ":clear" to the token, eg `[current-page:query:utm_source:clear]`, https://www.drupal.org/node/2972423